# Reversing string characters while keeping them in the same position

Tags: python, string

I'm looking to reverse a set of strings while keeping them in the same positions and also trying **not to use slicing or reverse()**. So if I had:

```
string = 'This is the string'
```

Using the reverse function, it would return:

```
'sihT si eht gnirts'
```

I made a function that does everything correct except for positioning:

```
def Reverse(string):
   length = len(string)
   emp = ""
   for i in range(length-1,-1,-1):
       emp += length[i]
   return emp
```

which returns;

```
gnirts a si sihT      # correct reverse, wrong positions
```

How can I get this reversed string back into the correct positions?

Comment: Just a suggestion, to be pythonic you shouldn't capitalize your function names. The convention is to capitalize class names and lower case/snake_case function names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def Reverse(string):
    length = len(string)
    emp = ""
    for i in range(length-1,-1,-1):
        emp += string[i]
    return emp

 myString = 'This is the string'
 print ' '.join([Reverse(word) for word in myString.split(' ')])
```

OUTPUT

```
sihT si eht gnirts
```

Answer (score 6):

Guess you want:

```
string = 'This is the string'

def Reverse(string):
    return ' '.join([s[::-1] for s in string.split(' ')])

print(Reverse(string))
```

Gives:

```
sihT si eht gnirts
```

~

Comment: I'm trying not to use slicing or reverse

Comment: Thanks for the answer though, in 99% of cases this is a more than acceptable answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using two `for` loops and `str.split()`:

```
def reverse_pos(string):
    a = ''
    splitted = string.split()
    length = len(splitted)
    for i, elm in enumerate(splitted):
        k = ''  # temporar string that holds the reversed strings
        for j in elm:
            k = j + k
        a += k
        # Check to add a space to the reversed string or not
        if i < length - 1:
            a += ' '
    return a


string = 'This is the string'
print(reverse_pos(string))
```

Or better:

```
def reverse_pos(string):
    for elm in string.split():
        k = ''  # temporar string that holds the reversed strings
        for j in elm:
            k = j + k
        yield k


string = 'This is the string'
print(' '.join(reverse_pos(string)))
```

Output:

```
sihT si eht gnirts
```

**NB:** The main idea here is split by spaces and reverse each elmement. This will reverse and keep the words in their position in the primary string.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing too different from what's been posted so far:

```
string = "This is the string"
string_reversed = " ".join(["".join(reversed(word)) for word in string.split()])
print(string_reversed)
```

*edit* Just read the original post again, sorry.